# CSS-Styles-How to display Basket Total below products

Tags: javascript, css

How can I display basket total below the products, with the below code both products and basket totals are displaying in the same line. where I am doing wrong?  Iam grabbing Div products from cart page 
        -----HTMl- cart Page-------------

```
          <div class ="product-header">     [![enter image description here][1]][1]
            <h5 class ="product-title">PRODUCT</h5>
            <h5 class ="price">PRICE</h5>
            <h5 class ="quantity" >QUANTITY</h5>
            <h5 class ="total">TOTAL</h5>       
       </div>

       <div class ="products"> 
       </div> 
       </div>


    /* main.js*/
    // function  to display on cart page
   function displayCart() {
       let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");  
       cartItems =JSON.parse(cartItems);
       let productContainer = document.querySelector(".products");
       let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

   if(cartItems && productContainer) {
        productContainer.innerHTML ='';
        Object.values(cartItems).map(item => {
        productContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class="products"> // This products is from cart page Div  
        <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        <img src="./images/${item.tag}.jpg">
        <span>${item.name}</span>   
        </div>
        <div class="price">$${item.price}</div>
        <div class="quantity">
        <ion-icon class ="decrease" name="caret-back-circle-outline"> 
        </ion-icon>
        <span>${item.incart}</span>
        <ion-icon class ="increase" name="caret-forward-circle-outline"> 
       </ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="total">$${item.incart * item.price},00 </div>

        `;
    });

     productContainer.innerHTML += `
      <div class="basketTotalContainer">
        <h4 class="basketTotalTitle"> Basket Total </h4>
        <h4 class ="basketTotal">
        $${cartCost},00
        </h4>
    </div>
    `;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your styles are I'd suggest looking into this class 
basketTotalContainer. Most likely the display property is being overridden. To be on a new line you want this div to be a block level element. Not inline.